# How to scan a remote device for ESTABLISHED tcp port

Tags: android, networking

My application is scanning available ports where I'm interested in open/established session on a remote IP address.

My code below returns 22 (ssh) and 902 (Vmware) where a netstat -an returns:

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.160:60376     216.58.208.238:443  (google)     ESTABLISHED

How can I retrieve the established session for a remote device?

My code for available ports (I do a loop on ports):

```
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
                socket.close();
```

Comment: `My code below returns` ??? Those three statements do not return anything. Where are you talking about?

Comment: my point is that every port scans on device behaves the same with trying to connect to ports with looping from 1 to 65536 if you'd like. This shows you the ports available not the established ones. My question is if you know a technique how to get the established ones. I know how to do on the device where my app is running. Not on a remote device.